# Goodbye Friday night!

Tags: phrases

Do you use expressions like **"Goodbye Friday night!"**, or **"Goodbye my holiday!"** when you have some changes in your life plans under some circumstances? For example, you have some plans for Friday night but you have received a call from your manager, and you have to go to work now. If you don't use those ones, please write some common expressions for this case.

Comment: "There go my plans for Friday night!"

Comment: "Bang goes my Friday night!"

Comment: **Goodbye Love** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodbye_Love_(film))

Comment: 'Goodnight Vienna' for unconsciousness or death.

Comment: This site works best with questions that have objective answers, not opinions or personal reports. If you rephrase it to ask about what's normal in English rather than a poll of what the random assortment of users here do, it'll be a better question